# Tinymce does not display on mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, tinymce

I have tinymce text editor,but it doesnt load on mozilla firefox,do I need to add some add-ons for mozilla or enable something to make it work.
Plus it works fine on google chrome.

this is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        force_p_newlines : false,


        plugins: [
                "advlist autolink autosave image link  lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                "table contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor paste fullpage textcolor"
        ],

        toolbar1: "newdocument fullpage | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect | cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | undo redo | link unlink anchor image media | inserttime preview ",
        toolbar2: "forecolor backcolor | table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript | charmap emoticons | print fullscreen | ltr rtl | spellchecker | visualchars visualblocks nonbreaking template pagebreak restoredraft ",

        image_advtab: true,
        menubar: false,
        toolbar_items_size: 'small',

        style_formats: [
                {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
                {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
                {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
                {title: 'Table styles'},
                {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
        ],

        templates: [
                {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
                {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
        ]

});</script>
```

this line i use to call it

```
 <textarea id="to1" name="questiontext" ></textarea>
```

Comment: It's not a `Java` question, remove `Java` tag!

Comment: @MJafarMash You can edit other people's posts you know. :-)

Comment: @SilverlightFox but it have to have a minimum number of characters, i guess i cannot edit only to remove a tag

Comment: @MJafarMash Yes you can only edit tags.

Comment: @SilverlightFox Oh! I didn't know! thanks!